# Hibernate caching on dynamic changing parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-cache

I have a sample hibernate sql statement as below. As this query has three bind parameters which will vary for different criterias, Would PostComment Entity be eligible for ehcache in Hibernate? please advise.

```
select pc from PostComment pc join fetch pc.post p where pc.id = :id and pc.startdate= :startdate and pc.enddate= :enddate
```